# Beta sites meta-migration does not autodirect

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, area-51, beta-phase, stackexchange-2.0

[This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2301/identify-the-games-behind-the-stackexchange-offline-control-layouts-closed) was migrated from gaming to meta.gaming, but I'm not automatically redirected to the migrated version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's correct and by design; you would only be redirected if the question was deleted.

Behaves the same on all sites.

Comment: ah, I usually stumble upon migrated questions long after the original has been deleted, so I didn't notice